# Is there a way to see what assemblies my program references in VS 2013 C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have a need to identify if I'm referencing a specific assembly in my project/solution. I've not found an easy way to do this (I want to do it at design time and not run time if possible).

Seems this should be easy, but I'm not finding a way in VS, directly. Ideally, if I could see what/where I'm referencing (assuming that I am) would be great, too, so I can remove such references from my code.

Simply searching for "Assembly." in my code turns up nothing, now, for example.

**A concrete example is in order: I want to know if I use anything in System.Reflection.Assembly. And I'd like to find the code that does it (in my source) if I do.**

Comment: Are we talking programatically or just viewing them in the UI??

Comment: Umm, looking in the References folder or property page doesn't work because...?

Comment: Because it can't tell me if I reference something in System.Reflection.Assembly.  That's what I need to know (and where in my code if it's being used).

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies Method ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe... I think what that does is report all assemblies listed (kinda like above, inside VS 2013). I really want to know, by way of analyzing the code, which ones I actually am using/need. I want to verify that I'm not using System.Reflection.Assembly, for example. Maybe my original statement was not clear (or even wrong!). I'll update to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (almost all versions) open the Solution Explorer window the second "folder" is the References section. If you expand that you'll be able to see the referenced assemblies.

[image]

Image from [robowiki](http://robowiki.net/)

Comment: Not really. That shows me all references to assemblies I've added, but if the assembly I want is inside one of those, I won't see it. For example, System contains a boatload of other things and I need to know if I'm referencing one of them.